# La suma de todos los elementos con la fecha mínima - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos a la comunidad.

Tengo el siguiente script que es parte de un procedimiento almacenado

```sql
SELECT  AD.IdPersona1 , PC.CodCuenta, PC.Descripcion, PCP.CodCuenta CodCtaPadre, PCP.Descripcion NombreCtaPadre,  CAST(p.rCodDocIdentidad AS INTEGER)TipoDocID,p.DocIdentidad,p.ApPaterno+' '+p.ApMaterno+' '+p.Nombres Trabajador,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='D' THEN AD.Importe ELSE 0 END) TotalDebe,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='H' THEN AD.Importe ELSE 0 END) AS TotalHaber,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='D' THEN AD.FechaDoc ELSE NULL END)FechaDebe,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='H' THEN AD.FechaDoc ELSE NULL END)FechaHaber                               
                FROM CONTA_ASIENTO_CTBLE_DTLLE AD WITH(NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN LIBROS_CONTABLES LC WITH(NOLOCK)ON AD.CodEmpresa = LC.CodEmpresa 
                                                                            AND AD.NroLibro = LC.NroLibro
                    INNER JOIN PLAN_CONTABLE PC WITH(NOLOCK)ON AD.CodEmpresa = PC.CodEmpresa AND AD.NroPlanConta = PC.NroPlanConta 
                    INNER JOIN PLAN_CONTABLE PCP WITH(NOLOCK)ON PC.NroCuentaPadre=PCP.NroPlanConta
                    -- CODIGO RELACION: Sólo Personas                   
                    INNER JOIN PERSONAS P WITH(NOLOCK)ON AD.IdPersona1 = P.IDPersona 
                WHERE AD.CodEmpresa = '01'
                    AND AD.CodPeriodo BETWEEN '202101' AND '202112'
                    AND (PC.CodCuenta LIKE '14%')
                    AND p.DocIdentidad = '40441442'
                    AND AD.NroLibro <> '21'
                GROUP BY AD.IdPersona1 ,PC.CodCuenta, PC.Descripcion, PCP.CodCuenta, PCP.Descripcion                        
                             ,p.rCodDocIdentidad,p.DocIdentidad,p.ApPaterno,p.ApMaterno,p.Nombres
```

El mismo arroja el siguiente resultado:
[image: Resultado1]

Lo que deseo es obtener la suma de toda la columna `TotalDeber` y `TotalHaber`; busco que sea sin transformar todo el script de arriba en una subconsulta, pero no me resulta e intentado hacerlo subconsulta. Además la columna `FechaDebe` debe ser la más antigua, la columna `FechaHaber` no importa mucho y deberá ser la que está emparejada con la `FechaDebe`.

Algo así debe ser el resultado:

| idPersona1 | codCuenta | Descrip | CodCtaP | NomCtaP | TipoDoc | DocId | Trabajador | TotalDebe | TotalHaber | FechaDebe | FechaHaber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3007 | 14131 | Viaticos | 1413 | Entregas a rendir cuenta | 1 | 40441442 | MELENDEZ CORONADO JUAN MARINO | 66748.75 | 65973.21 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 |

Mi intento es el siguiente:

```sql
SELECT AG.IdPersona1, AG.CodCuenta, AG.Descripcion, AG.CodCtaPadre, AG.NombreCtaPadre, AG.TipoDocID, AG.DocIdentidad, AG.Trabajador, SUM(TotalDebe), SUM(TotalHaber), MIN(FechaDebe), MIN(FechaHaber) 
FROM (

SELECT  AD.IdPersona1 , PC.CodCuenta, PC.Descripcion, PCP.CodCuenta CodCtaPadre, PCP.Descripcion NombreCtaPadre,  CAST(p.rCodDocIdentidad AS INTEGER)TipoDocID,p.DocIdentidad,p.ApPaterno+' '+p.ApMaterno+' '+p.Nombres Trabajador,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='D' THEN AD.Importe ELSE 0 END) TotalDebe,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='H' THEN AD.Importe ELSE 0 END) AS TotalHaber,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='D' THEN AD.FechaDoc ELSE NULL END)FechaDebe,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN AD.TIPODH='H' THEN AD.FechaDoc ELSE NULL END)FechaHaber                               
                FROM CONTA_ASIENTO_CTBLE_DTLLE AD WITH(NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN LIBROS_CONTABLES LC WITH(NOLOCK)ON AD.CodEmpresa = LC.CodEmpresa 
                                                                            AND AD.NroLibro = LC.NroLibro
                    INNER JOIN PLAN_CONTABLE PC WITH(NOLOCK)ON AD.CodEmpresa = PC.CodEmpresa AND AD.NroPlanConta = PC.NroPlanConta 
                    INNER JOIN PLAN_CONTABLE PCP WITH(NOLOCK)ON PC.NroCuentaPadre=PCP.NroPlanConta
                    -- CODIGO RELACION: Sólo Personas                   
                    INNER JOIN PERSONAS P WITH(NOLOCK)ON AD.IdPersona1 = P.IDPersona 
                WHERE AD.CodEmpresa = '01'
                    AND AD.CodPeriodo BETWEEN '202101' AND '202112'
                    AND (PC.CodCuenta LIKE '14%')
                    AND p.DocIdentidad = '40441442'
                    AND AD.NroLibro <> '21'
                GROUP BY AD.IdPersona1 ,PC.CodCuenta, PC.Descripcion, PCP.CodCuenta, PCP.Descripcion                        
                             ,p.rCodDocIdentidad,p.DocIdentidad,p.ApPaterno,p.ApMaterno,p.Nombres 
                             
                             ) AG 
GROUP BY AG.IdPersona1
```

Pero existen en el muchos errores que aún no soluciono, espero puedan apoyarme.

Gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Comment: Cuáles errores?

Comment: Isanchezo, cuando queremos hacer uso de subquery puede al principio quedarse lastimoso. Aconsejo que separe tu procedimiento en partes. Haga un plan de que necesites. Crie tablas auxiliares para guardar sumas, cálculos e al final generar el resultado que necesitas.